# Running Heroku for local and deployment with settings modules

Tags: django, heroku

I've setted up a Django project using settings modules, a `base.py`, `development.py`, and `production.py` but I'm a little confused on how to run the project locally and remotely.

So, I can run `python manage.py runserver --settings=<project>.settings.development` and everything goes alright but my doubt is: How can I run it through `heroku local` giving the settings option? It will also help to run it on remotely with production settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Environment variables

In `__init__.py` of your settings directory add:

```
import os
from .base import *

environment = os.environ.get("ENV")

if environment == development:
    from .development import *

else:
    from .production import *
```

this will load the development settings module if the value of **ENV** is set to **development**, otherwise by default it will load the **production** settings module.

[Configuring environment variables in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)